# How to get max value of a grouped counted variable in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table like this;

```
recordID| netcall    | sign | activity | netid
1       | group1     | wa1  | 1        | 20
2       | group2     | wa2  | 2        | 30
3       | group1     | wa2  | 1        | 20
4       | group2     | wa3  | 2        | 30
5       | group1     | wa1  | 1        | 40
6       | group3     | wa4  | 3        | 50
7       | group3     | wa4  | 3        | 50
8       | group1     | wa2  | 1        | 40
9       | group1     | wa1  | 1        | 40
10      | group2     | wa4  | 2        | 60
```

What I need from that is:

```
Netcall | count | activity | netid
Group1  | 3     | 1        | 40
Group2  | 2     | 2        | 30
Group3  | 2     | 3        | 50
```

I thought I could;

```
SELECT MAX(xx.mycount) AS MAXcount
  FROM (SELECT COUNT(tt.sign) AS mycount ,tt.activity
        FROM NetLog tt
       WHERE ID <> 0
       GROUP BY netcall) xx
```

But this only brings up the grand total not broken down by netcall. I don't see an example of this question but I'm sure there is one, I'm just asking it wrong.

Comment: Where is the MAX in your desired result?

Comment: From your sample data it seems like all group1 have the same activity 1, all group2 have the same activity 2 and all all group3 have the same activity 3. Is this the case?

Comment: your table doesnt have `ID` or `0`, also explain the logic for the group and that result

Comment: what is your mysql version?

Comment: MAX of course is a MySQL function. #forpas yes the activity is just another variable I need to pull from the table. #Juan Carolos Oropeza the variable recordID is actually what most would call ID and is always unique.

Comment: Why not just do this: `SELECT COUNT(sign), MAX(activity) FROM NetLog GROUP BY netcall`?

Comment: I know MAX is a MySQL function. But `row_number()` is only available on v8+

Comment: group 1 can have different activities? In that case you want to show the group/activity with the largest count? or there is only one activities and in that case is just a group/count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example and desire output are too basic, you should try to expand so include more cases.

Right now you can get the desire output with:

```
SELECT `netcall`, COUNT(*) as `total`, MAX(`activity`) as `activity`
FROM t
GROUP BY `netcall`;
```

My guess is you can have different activities for group so you need multiples steps

- Calculate the `COUNT()` for `GROUP BY netcall, activity` I call it `q`
- Then see what is the `MAX(total)` for each `netcall` I call it `p`
- Now you reuse `q` as `o` you have all the count, so just select the one with the  max count.

**[SQL DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cg9gNp2S5VpyWkQZQRJyxZ/1)**

```
SELECT o.`netcall`, o.total, o.`activity`
FROM (
      SELECT `netcall`, COUNT(*) `total`, `activity`
      FROM t
      GROUP BY `netcall`, `activity`
     ) o 
JOIN (     
      SELECT `netcall`, MAX(`total`) as `total`
      FROM (
        SELECT `netcall`, COUNT(*) `total`
        FROM t
        GROUP BY `netcall`, `activity`
      ) q  
      GROUP BY `netcall`
     ) p
  ON o.`netcall` = p.`netcall`
 AND o.`total` = p.`total`
```

With MySQL v8+ you can use cte and window function to simplify a little bit

```
with group_count as (
  SELECT `netcall`, COUNT(*) as total, `activity`        
  FROM t
  GROUP BY `netcall`, `activity`
), group_sort as (
  SELECT `netcall`, total, `activity`, 
          RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY `netcall`, `activity` ORDER BY total DESC) as rnk
  FROM group_count
)  
SELECT *
FROM group_sort
WHERE rnk = 1
```

Comment: I did not ask the question correctly, my apologies. Please look at my table data and output again I've edited it. I need each netcalls maximum count based on netid. Or what netid for each group has the highest count?

Comment: You still havent answer my question on comments. What is your MySQL version and can you have multiple activities for group and how you handle those? and how you handle ties?

Comment: I'm giving #Juan_Carlos_Oropeza credit for leading me to the solution. I had to change one of the variables but by doing so his solution (the first one with the join) is what in the end worked. I don't have MySQL 8 or above yet.

Answer (score 0):

This question is asked (and answered) every day on SO; it even has its own chapter in the MySQL manual, but anyway...

```
SELECT a.netcall
     , b.total
     , a.activity
  FROM netlog a
  JOIN
     ( SELECT netcall 
            , MAX(record_id) record_id
            , COUNT(*) total
         FROM netlog 
        GROUP 
           BY netcall 
    ) b
   ON b.netcall = a.netcall
  AND b.record_id = a.record_id
```

Comment: You probably miss a JOIN some where

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Glad to see someone's paying attention!

Comment: Please notice in the example output that the count is of how many signs (wa1, wa2, etc.) there are in each of the groups (netcall). Group1 has 5, Group2 has 3 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT k.netcall, k.netID,  MAX(k.logins) highest, 
AVG(k.logins) average, netDate, activity
                          FROM
                            (SELECT netID, netcall, COUNT(*) logins, DATE(`logdate`) as netDate, activity
                               FROM NetLog
                              WHERE netID <> 0 AND status = 1
                                AND netcall <> '0' AND netcall <> ''
                              GROUP BY netcall, netID) k
                            GROUP BY netcall  
                            ORDER BY highest DESC
```

Resulted in:

```
Net Call    Highest Average Net ID  Sub Net Of...   ICS
214   309   Map Date    Activity
MESN    65  41.5294 339     214     309 MAP 2017-09-03  MESN
W0KCN   34  14.9597 1       214     309 MAP 2016-03-15  KCNARES Weekly 2m Voice Net
W0ERH   31  31.0000 883     214     309 MAP 2018-10-12  Johnson Co. Radio Amateurs Club Meeting Net
KCABARC 29  22.3333 57      214     309 MAP 2016-10-10  KCA Blind Amateurs Weekly 2m Voice Net
```

....